# Kriyah at the Kosel for Women

Tags: women, clothing, mourning-aveilus, kotel-western-wall

Do women tear Kriyah at the kosel?

Comment: According to those who tear at the kotel in general.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17187/1059

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **Yes** (as it says in **SHU"T Minchas Shlomo** 1:76).

(**Shu"t Ginat Veradim** 14:5:8) says that a women should tear the inner garment as if not, it would involve a breach of dignity.

Comment: Could you tell me who the SHU"T Minchas Shlomo and the SHU"T Ginat Veradim are by writing a bit about them as answers to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/what-are-all-of-these-halachic-sources)?

Comment: I think that this is what the answer meant, but I do not have a minchas shlomo or ginas veradim (what he wrote in the name of the ginas veradim doesn't make senee).

Comment: Minchat Shelomo 1:76 is not about keriya. Am I looking at the wrong teshuva? You are referring to Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach? The one I see is all about afka'inhu lekiddushin.