# Tearing keriyah for ladies mourning in public

Tags: women, clothing, tznius-modesty, mourning-aveilus

Is it considered to be "un-tznius" (immodest) for ladies to tear keriyah (rip their clothes in mourning) in public?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2219/1059

Comment: That's not a reason to do a full rollback whereby you also lose the explanation and appropriate tags. Just edit the word tear back in if you want.

Comment: Who voted to close as off topic?

Comment: @AdamMosheh typically frum women are wearing more than one layer. they tear the top layer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch rules ([YD 340:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=343)) that women and men have an equal obligation in terms of keri'a, but that women should turn their undershirt around after tearing it before tearing her overshirt. Furthermore, in [:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=343) he rules that a woman who performed keri'a is allowed to perform a non-professional stitch-up immediately after tearing, whereas a man would have to wait 30 days to do so when tearing for his parents.

Comment: Why shouldn't men do the same? Modesty is for both genders.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Modesty is for both genders and each gender has a different way of being modest.

Comment: @AA - But why should men be less modest than women?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Not less. Different.

Comment: @AA - Please explain why not less, then.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I'm not sure what you want exactly but I see no reason why one should be less than the other. So...not less.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Because women have breasts, and men don't. So a tear in the top would be immodest for women only.